# Array out of bounds error when trying to save attachments in vba/sql

Tags: arrays, vba, outlook

I managed to get the code to save the attachment, but now I have put some conditions on it I keep getting array out of bounds error. I did have the attachments.item as (x) but my co-worker advised this wouldn't work. I thought I'd ask the experts anyway.

When I run it in debug mode attachments.item(x) goes from 1 straight to 820.

Here is a fragment of my code:

For i = 1 To EmailCount
    With ObjParentFolder.Items(i)

```
    If .MessageClass = "IPM.Note" And .ReceivedTime >= teste Then
        Found = False
        If PreviousRex = True Then
            For x = 0 To RexCnt
                If .SenderName = Data(x).Sender And .ReceivedTime = Data(x).Received Then
                    Found = True
                End If
            Next x
        End If
        If Found = False Then
                    rex.AddNew
                        rex.Fields("MailItemPath") = ObjParentFolder.Name
                        rex.Fields("ReceivedTime") = .ReceivedTime
                        rex.Fields("MailDate") = DateValue(.ReceivedTime)
                        rex.Fields("MailHour") = Left(TimeValue(.ReceivedTime), 2)
                        rex.Fields("Subject") = .Subject
                        rex.Fields("SenderName") = .SenderName
                        rex.Fields("MSGBody") = .Body
                        rex.Fields("Last_Updated") = Now
                        rex.Fields("Updated_By") = UCase(CurrentUserName())
                        rex.Fields("new") = True
                        rex.Fields("W_ID") = prop & rex.Fields("ID")
                        TmpID = rex.Fields("W_ID")
                    rex.Update


        End If

        'If .Attachments.Count > 0 Then
        '   For p = 1 To .Attachments.Count
        '       Select Case Right(.Attachments.Item(p).Filename, 4)
        '           Case ".xls"
        '               .Attachments.Item(p).SaveAsFile (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\attachments" & "_" & TmpID & "_" & .Attachments.Item(p).Filename)
        '          Case ".zip"
        '                .Attachments.Item(p).SaveAsFile (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\attachments" & "_" & TmpID & "_" & .Attachments.Item(p).Filename)
        '            Case ".doc"
        '                .Attachments.Item(p).SaveAsFile (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\attachments" & "_" & TmpID & "_" & .Attachments.Item(p).Filename)
        '            Case Else
        '                .Attachments.Item(p).Delete
        '       End Select
        '   Next p
        'End If
    End If
End With
```

Next i

Answer (score 0):

You are deleting attachments in the loop, thus changing the total count. Use a down loop:

```
For p = .Attachments.Count to 1 step -1
```

It is also a good idea to avoid using multiple dot notation. Cache the attachments collection before entering the loop and retrieve the attachment only once

dim attachments
dim attach 
set attachments = .Attachments
If attachments.Count > 0 Then

```
       For p = .Attachments.Count to 1 step -1
           set attach = attachments.Item(p)
           Select Case Right(attach.Filename, 4)
               Case ".xls"
                   attach.SaveAsFile (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\attachments" & "_" & TmpID & "_" & attach.Filename)
              Case ".zip"
                    attach.SaveAsFile (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\attachments" & "_" & TmpID & "_" & attach.Filename)
                Case ".doc"
                    attach.SaveAsFile (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\attachments" & "_" & TmpID & "_" & attach.Filename)
                Case Else
                    attach.Delete
           End Select
       Next p
    End If
```